# Return data to the original webpage after a series of back and forth requests

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website structured like so :

"Client side" : HTML / CSS / Javascript
"Server side" : PHP

Client side, when a user pushes a button, **he's redirected to a page** (*bold because the `click` action does not trigger a php script, the redirection itself does with `window.open("https://...../, '_self');`*) that toggles a series of scripts back and forth to get, check, and validate data from various other websites and storing some of them in my DB.

Once this is all done, at the end of my last PHP script i need to redirect my user to the original webpage with a bunch of divs and spans and whatsnot updated with the data retrieved.

Typically at the end i'd have this

```
header( "Location: $originalURL" );
```

How should i redirect my user while sending back data to the original webpage all the data i need to update my html elements ?
Through a POST request ?
By doing something similar to this :
`header( "Location: $originalURL/?data1:$data1&data2:$data2" );` ?
which i would really much avoid not only for its uglyness or unaesthetical aspect, but most of all for the process to be entirely transparant from the user point of view.

EDIT (to explain the 'flow') :

1. `mywebsite.com/mypage/index.**html**`
2. js click function (`window.open(mywebsite.come/mypage/processes/index.php)`)
3. series of back and forths between external URLs to get data
4. last call back to my domain `mywebsite.com/mypage/stepX/index.**php**`
5. redirection to `mywebsite.com/mypage/index.**html**`
6. `mywebsite.com/mypage/index.**html**` gets the data from step 5 and updates html elements via its `script.js`

And i'm stuck at step6.
How does my script.js get all the new data directly with the redirection from my server-side PHP script ?

Comment: Maybe a PHP session?

Comment: i want to make clear that my website is not based on PHP at all. In my case, php is just a script language that does server-side stuff and transfers data to javascript only if i did an ajax request. But i don't know how to send data back to javascript from straight PHP

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `header(location:)` here because it is only **a way to force browsers** to brutally get to a page.

You need to use `require_once()` function which is meant to include a PHP file into another. In that way, you would **transform your HTML page into a PHP file** and you'll be able to access to variables from the file you required.

Passing an HTML file into PHP file is pretty straightforward, it will allow you to **transform your PHP variables into JS variables**.

Comment: But i don't want to transform my webpage structure.
I only want to send data to javascript on load from PHP script ending it's thing.  
That basically tells me that i'm going to find a mecanism that tells the webpage on load with cookies i guess that data have been updated, which confuses me cause it kind of destroys the security goal i was trying to reach by doing the back and forth requests through server-php only